# Npm process are staying till CTRL+C press

Tags: node.js, npm

I am working with Webpack 2 and I am using NPM to execute every commands (like build/tests etc.). Pretty standard.

But sometimes I see that some process (deployment/compiling/testing etc.) can be like : freezed/stacked/waiting/lagged.  SO it just stays and waiting for something..the process restore their normal flow after a CTRL+C pressing.

What it can be? And how I can fight with that? thanks for any information!

Comment: how long does an task take to complete ?you can make it output more information as there might be something that makes it behave that way.

Comment: Standard - more that 40 seconds. But in case of freezing - I don't know. 
So I 'll check it. Thanks.